# 3-term arithmetic progression

Tags: algorithms

I am a computer science student, I am studying an algorithm course independently.
In the course I got stuck with this question:

$A$ 3-term arithmetic progression is 3 integers ${a < b < c}$ such that ${a + c = 2b}$. Given a set
of integers $A\subseteq\left\{1,...,n\right\}$, find an $O(n \log n)$ time algorithm that computes the number of 3-term arithmetic progressions in $A$.

I tried to solve the problem, I tried to use the information that this is arithmetic progression.

$b = a + d$, $c = a + 2d$

${a < b < c} \Longrightarrow {a < a + d < a+2d}$

${a + c = 2b} \Longrightarrow {a + a+2d = 2(a+d)}$

But it does not help me solve the problem.

Comment: Try using FFT somehow.

Comment: Maybe I can calculate $a-d$ and $a + d$ in FFT. Maybe I can calculate a-d and a + d in FFT.
But a , b and c should be polynomial, I do not think it is possible.
$A(w^{j})=A_{odd}(w^{2j}) + A_{even}(w^{2j})$ . $A_{odd}$  maybe equal to $ a$ and $A_{even}$ is $c$

Comment: consider the support of the set $A$ as a binary string and apply FFT. For example, if $n=4$ and $A=\{1,2,4\}$ you apply FFT to $(1,1,0,1).$

Comment: i found the solution here: https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-count-the-number-of-3-term-arithmetic-progressions-in-a-subset-of-1-n-using-an-algorithm-which-runs-in-O-n-log-n-time

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.